# Set Background Image or Gradient in Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

How do I set a background image for Monaco editor? If that's not possible, can it have a background gradient? The editor is supposed to be a kind of decorative feature of the website, and it won't do if it can't be decorated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background gradient goes into the `background-image` property, so often if you can do one, you can do the other. If you'd like, you can set the background image on the div with class `.monaco-editor`. However, you must realize there is a div with class `.lines-content` that has height and width set to `1e+06px`, and the background of this div will override yours because it's so big. You'll have to unset the background on this, particularly if you want to use a gradient.

This will, however, leave the `.margin` and the `.minimap` untouched. You'll have to target those specifically if you want the background changed. If you want these to share the background with the editor, you'll have to use `background-attachment: fixed`.

I will warn that there are plenty of colorations the editor does that you'll probably have to account for to make everything work with your new background. Highlighting, outlining, tooltips, and so forth.